# What is the proper status code for a maintenance page redirect?

Tags: redirect, http-status-codes, maintenance-mode

While performing some upcoming maintenance, I'm going to have to redirect all site traffic to a maintenance page briefly. What's the proper status code to use for the redirect?

503 makes sense, but it's not technically a redirection status. 302 is a temp redirect, but wondering if that might have implications if the site is being spidered at the time.

Comment: That's an interesting question. It seems that Google does not have an official statement on this: http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agoogle.com+http+redirects+-301

Comment: Google has since posted their take on this. It more or less matches johannes's answer. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-deal-with-planned-site-downtime.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would use 503, too, combined with a Retry-After header. A proper robot should know how to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

[302 Found](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) would probably be the classic way - not a permanent redirect. You want it to be temporary though, so when the spider came back, it would try it again, but which time, it should be back up.  A 301 would indicate to not go to the original.

The [500 series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_503#5xx_Server_Error) are errors, not what you want to indicate.

Comment: True, but 503 does explicitly refer to being down for maintenance, which is obviously a less severe error than a 500 for example.

Answer (score 1):

Use 503, and if you want to redirect, do it via JavaScript on the served page.

Just be careful not to lose the original URL (save it as a query parameter, for example), as users are expecting to return to the page they were looking for when the maintenance is done.